# animate 3 object

Tags: java, swing

I need to draw a rectange,circle and line and then animate them(press left -> it(all objects) moves left for examp.)

I draw objects like this

```
class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

int x = 10;
int y = 10;
public MyCanvas()
{
    Action someaction = new AbstractAction(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            x+=30;
            //revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    };
    this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), someaction);
}        
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
g.drawRect(x,y, 200, 200); 
g.drawOval(x, y, 50, 50);
g.drawLine(x, y, 50, 30);
  }
}
```

But it doesn't move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use `paintComponent(Graphics g)` for Swing `JComponents` instead of `paint(Graphics g)`
2. use `KeyBindings` for `KeyEvents`  for Swing `JComponents`
3. put Objects (prepare before `paintComponent(Graphics g)`) to the Array, paint elements from Array in `paintComponent(Graphics g)`

Comment: 1.ok 2. where to put `getinputMap` 3. `for` inside `paintComponent`?